# Soap XML Output Creates an Array

Tags: php, arrays, xml, domdocument, soap-client

I am calling a web service using SoapClient and attempting to pull data from the response output. I have modified the Soap response so that it displays in XML.

I did so by writing this: `$resultxml = htmlentities($client->__getLastResponse()) . "\n";`.

If you do a simple `print_r($resultxml);` you receive the full output, obviously.

What I am having trouble with is using `DomDocument` with `$resultxml` to create my `techData` array. If I copy and paste the Soap output and create a stand-alone XML file with it, then add it to `$dom->loadXML();` the `techData` array is created perfectly. However, when I try to pull the XML from `$resultxml` I receive a blank array.

Any ideas as to why this is? Should I consider revising `$resultxml = htmlentities($client->__getLastResponse()) . "\n";`? Am I calling it incorrectly?

Thanks so much.

My PHP with my SoapClient request and array code:

```
<?php
 $client = new SoapClient('http://services.chromedata.com/Description/7b?wsdl', array('trace' => 1));
 $account = ['number'=>"", 'secret'=>"", 'country'=>"US",    'language'=>"en"];
 $switch =  ["ShowAvailableEquipment", "ShowExtendedTechnicalSpecifications", "ShowExtendedDescriptions"];
 $vin = $_POST["b12"];

$result = $client->describeVehicle([
'accountInfo' => $account,
'switch' => $switch,
'vin' => $vin
]);

$resultxml = htmlentities($client->__getLastResponse()) . "\n";

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadXML($resultxml);


$techData = [];
foreach ( $dom->getElementsByTagName('technicalSpecification') as $techSpec )   {
$id = $techSpec->getElementsByTagName('titleId')->item(0)->nodeValue;
$techData [$id]= $techSpec->getElementsByTagName('value')->item(0)->getAttribute("value")."<br>";

}

print_r($techData);
echo "<br>";
```

Comment: Try removing the call to `htmlentities()` - so just use `$resultxml = $client->__getLastResponse();`

Comment: That was it, thanks again @NigelRen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use [`htmlentities()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php) - this will encode the markup, so

```
<S:Body>
```

becomes

```
&lt;S:Body&gt;
```

thiw ill not work if you then try to load it as an XML document, so just use

```
$resultxml = $client->__getLastResponse();
```